# What do multiple increments mean in a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm reading code and I come across this code:

`for (p = prevp->s.ptr; ; prevp = p, p = p->s.ptr)`

How should I interpret it? Does the for loop have multiple increments? I've seen multiple conditions before, separated by comma, but I never saw multiple increments before.

Comment: That's not a multiple increment strictly though,former one is assignment, the latter is the incremental code strictly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do multiple operations in increment part of for loop in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236658/is-it-possible-to-do-multiple-operations-in-increment-part-of-for-loop-in-c-c)

Comment: On a different note, I'd avoid for loops without an termination condition. You can always exit the loop with a break, but if you forget it, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop has the following format:

```
for( <initialization>; <condition>; <recurring operation> ) ....
```

*`<initialization>`* is taking place before the loop is entered first time (if at all). 
*`<recurring operation>`* is performed *after* each iteration. 
*`<condition>`* is checked before each iteration.

In your case: 
`<initialization>` = `p = prevp->s.ptr` - initializing p to some pointer value 
`<condition>` = nothing. So the loop will run forever, unless there is a `break` statement or some other flow control expression breaking the loop encountered.
`<recurring operation>` = `prevp = p, p = p->s.ptr`. It is updating two variables here `prevp` and `p`, such that in the next iteration they both will have the new values. The coma operator is evaluated from left to right, so first `prevp` is updated, and next the `p`.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right format of the `for` loop?

Comment: @banach-space Your comment would be much more helpful if you were expanding a bit. But it's ok, I've figured it out. On the way on updating the answer

Comment: I figured you would figure it out yourself ;-)

Answer (score 5):

In this case, on every iteration of the loop, both statements are called. It appears to be some sort of linked-list. You can clearly see how this works if you write it as a while loop:

```
p = prevp->s.ptr;
while (true) {
    //Loop body here

    prevp = p;
    p = p->s.ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). Basically, the increment part of the `for` consists of an expression with the comma operator. So your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The formal syntax of `for` statement is:

```
for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
```

Any of `clause-1`, `expression-2`, and `expression-3` can allow multiple expressions in them by using the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).

In `clause-1`, you can initialize multiple variables.

```
for ( cp1 = s1, cp2 = s2; ...
```

In `expression-3`, you can change multiple variables.

```
for ( cp1 = s1, cp2 = s2; ...; ++cp1, ++cp2 )
```

In your case, `expression-3` is `prevp = p, p = p->s.ptr`.

Comment: `expression 2` allows only one expression.

Comment: @haccks, Not true. You can use the comma operator to have multiple expression there too. It will be pretty ugly code but the syntax allows it. See it working at http://ideone.com/3I0Vy2.

Comment: `i < 10, j < 20;` will ruin the purpose of using comma operator.

Comment: @haccks, I agree. That was just a quick and dirty hack to show that it is legal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two last expressions will be executed after each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement -

```
for (p = prevp->s.ptr; ; prevp = p, p = p->s.ptr)
```

Actually there is no multiple increment. At the beginning of the for loop we see `p =  prev->s.ptr` which is actually initialization of `p`.

Then the code placed in the for loop will be executed.

After that the `condition` portion is evaluated. Here there is no condition. So the loop continues unless it is break from inside the code block of the for-loop.

The the increment section of the for-loop is reached. Now `previous`  point to `p` and `p` point will takes the next value.