# Revisit curly braces and performance in C++

Tags: c++, performance

I know that this question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145425/does-adding-unnecessary-curly-brackets-in-a-c-program-slow-it-down-at-all/23149006#23149006), among other places, but none of the answers touched on the *reason* I was given (years ago) for the adverse performance impact of "unnecessary" curly braces.
In that light, I'd like to revisit this issue.

Briefly, I was told that:

```
if(true) 
    do_something();
```

is more performant than

```
if(true)
{
   do_something();
}
```

The reason given, as I recall, was because the compiler would introduce  a branch in the assembled code in the second case which could have a cumulative effect.

Now, I can *spell* complier, but beyond that I know very little about how they operate, so is the above theory true?  Was it ever true?

Comment: You need to not listen to whoever told you that.

Comment: Whoever told you that is either incompetent or malicious.

Comment: You were told blatant rubbish. Kick that person in the ass please (for incompetence).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, three times.

Comment: @SergeyA I already told you _it takes five_ ;-) ...

Comment: "would introduce a branch in the assembled code in the second case which could have a cumulative effect": independently of all the other comments, I can't really make sense of this sentence. Cumulative to what ???

Comment: I can see four possibilities: a) you're misremembering; b) you misunderstood; c) someone was wrong but you believed them because you thought they weren't clueless; d) you mistook a joke for a factual statement.

Comment: `the compiler would introduce a branch in the assembled code in the second case which could have a cumulative effect` what? It won't introduce a branch in the first branch? If a branchless instruction was used for the second case, so is the first case

Answer (score 1):

> so is the above theory true?

No.

> Was it ever true?

No.
Not even with the worst ancient compilers lacking clever optimization strategies I could imagine these statements would emit different assenbly code.

These would simply be emitted as a call to the `do_something` subroutine.

Comment: I guess, we can't rule out arcane compiler bugs?

Comment: @SergeyA I believe even Turbo C++ gets this right.

Answer (score 1):

In unoptimized as well as optimized generated code, those two statements would translate exactly to the same. The braces create a new scope where nothing is declared, so nothing can be implemented differently, semantically speaking. (Unless a dumb compiler would manage an empty stack frame for this inner block ?!)

Answer (score 0):

The "facts" you were given are completely madeup. There is no performance reduction at all, **as people have already mentioned in the very link you gave.**

There is no way for us to explain the reasoning of something that's not true.