# Why the Semicolon is not emptying the loop body?

Tags: c, for-loop

The semicolon at the end of the for loop is suppose to empty the body and create a null loop. But why this is printing `6`?

```
void main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++);
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes null loop(do nothing), but it does increment `i` to 6, and so after loop ends next print statement is executed

Comment: You probably wanted to ask why there was only one number printed instead of 5, or you really don't get loops.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that the empty statement terminated by the semicolon *is* the loop body.  This is not some kind of special case or magic significance of the semicolon.  It simply creates a `for` loop whose *body* does nothing, but that works in all respects like any other `for` loop.

Comment: Yoiu have a loop. What do you expect?

Comment: @zubergu no i know loops,i am asking why it is printing 6 now i got it.

Comment: @MathsManiac what else do you expect to be printed? You have a loop that does nothing except incrementing `i`. After the loop you print `i`. What do you expect to happen **after** the loop?

Answer (score 11):

The loop body is empty, otherwise it would print `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`. But the loop head runs nethertheless and in each iteration it increases `i`. When it reaches `6` which is not `<=5` the loop ends. Printing `i` after the loop prints `i` as `6`. Incrementing `i` is a side effect of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is.at the end of the loop `i` will be 6 and the  `printf` does this.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop `for(i=1;i<=5;i++);` will run exactly 5 times, incrementing i from 1 to 6 (even though the for loop body is a no-op). Thus, in here:

```
{
    printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

the program will print the current value of `i`, that is 6.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for fun

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) /* void */;

    /* floating block one */
    {
        int i = 42; /* new i, hides old i */
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }

    /* floating block two */
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain me this @pmg

Comment: @Magnus see this void main()
{
    int i;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++);
{
    int i = 42;
    printf("%d\n",i);
}
    printf("%d\n",i);
}

Comment: It should print 42 42,but printing 42 6

Comment: The second definition of `i` (the `42`), inside the "floating" block, creates a different variable efectively hiding the first one (there are two `i`s, but you can only access the innermost). When that block finishes, the other "floating" block starts with the previous `i` in scope.

Comment: How can it get back the previous valur that is "2"?It is supposed to be replaced with 42.

Comment: how 42 is being replaced by  6. @pmg

Comment: The `6` is not replaced by anything. It "lives" at the same time as the `42`, both have the same name but different scopes (and lifetimes). The `i` with value 42 exists and is available only inside its floating block. The `i` with value 6 exists inside all of the `main()` function, but is hidden inside the floating block of the other `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you declare the int outside the null loop, the value is saved outside the increment loop.

[Read more about it here](http://cinterviewquetions.blogspot.se/2011/11/what-is-difference-between-null-loop.html)

The extra brackets do not do anything here because the semicolon exits the loop.

[Read more about brackets here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568503/extra-brace-brackets-in-c-code)

Answer (score 1):

it is quite simple:

`for(i=1;i<=5;i++);` will be executed 5 times, from 1 to 5
then i=6  ends the for loop and then a new "scoped" statement is executed:

```
printf("%d\n",i);
```

therefore prints 6